# rails MONTHNAMES to_s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is the problem:

inside a lib i need to print MONTHNAMES to string

if i try

```
Date::MONTHNAMES.inspect
```

result is

=> "[nil, \"January\", \"February\", \"March\", \"April\", \"May\", \"June\", \"July\", \"August\", \"September\", \"October\", \"November\", \"December\"]"

that's good but i don't need the first element, so

```
month_names = Date::MONTHNAMES
month_names.shift
month_names.inspect
```

but

```
ActionView::TemplateError (can't modify frozen array)
```

there is any workaround?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Date::MONTHNAMES.slice(1,12).inspect
```

gives you all month (without the first `nil`).

Comment: `Date::MONTHNAMES.compact` is better

Answer (score 12):

...also gives you all month (without the first nil).

```
Date::MONTHNAMES.compact
```

Answer (score 2):

As showed in the error message `Date::MONTHNAMES` is a frozen object so you can not modify it(`shift` will modify it by ,well, shifting out the first element). You can achieve what you want by:

`puts Date::MONTHNAMES[1..-1].inspect`

Answer (score 1):

Although the slice/array indexing solution is probably better here, you can always dup a frozen array and work on the copy:

```
month_names = Date::MONTHNAMES.dup
month_names.shift
month_names.inspect
```

should give you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

`Date::MONTHNAMES.reject{|m| m.nil?}`